# WPDataTables show only filtered results

Tags: filter, hide, show

I want to modify the table on this wordpress page, i only have access to the admin panel.

http://cqpperu.org/colegiados/busqueda-de-colegiados

to only show results if any filter is applied. I didn't find any options on the wordpress plugin to do so. I've tried the solution offered in the WPDataTables forum but it didn't work. I've tried installing Custom css-js-php plugin to be able to insert code to that single page.

I managed to hide the table with CSS using this code

```
#table_1, #table_1_info, #table_1_paginate { display: none !important; }
```

but can't show it with JS.

I tried this code without luck.

```
jQuery("#table_1_filter input").keyup(function (e) {
if ($(this).val().length > 1) {
    $("#table_1,#table_1_info,#table_1_paginate").show();
} else {
    $("#table_1,#table_1_info,#table_1_paginate").hide();
    }
});
```

i'm very new to javascript so please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me too but after searching and applying codes online, I came up with this. Hope it works for you.

```
var $tb = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function($tb) {
   $tb('#table_1_filter input').on('keyup', function() {
        if( $tb(this).val().length > 3 ){ 
$tb('#table_1').attr('style','display: table !important'); } else { $tb('#table_1').attr('style','display: none !important'); }
    });
});
```

If anyone knows how to apply it to a specific table only, that would be great. Thanks!